# Express route not found in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I have an Express server running at `localhost:3001` and a create-react-app (CRA) at `localhost:3000`. The server is set up as below. The API calls are done from the client using `fetch`. All Express are working, except `/player`.

```
const express = require('express');
// other requires

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // serve static content
    // problem is on development
}    

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    // called by clicking <a> to localhost:3001/login
});

app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
    // called from app.get("/login") localhost:3001/callback
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function (req, res) {
    // called from various methods on server side
  });

app.get("/me", (req, res) => {
    // called from app.get("/callback") localhost:3001/me
});

app.get("/collection/tracks", (req, res) => {
    // called from component <CollectionTracks /> in componentDidMount using fetch("/collection/tracks")
});

app.get("/player"), (req, res) => {
    // called from component <FooterPlayer /> in componentDidMount using fetch("/player")
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Can someone explain why it's fine to fetch `/collection/tracks` but `/player` returns:

- "Cannot GET /player" if I go to localhost:3001/player;
- "GET http://localhost:3000/player 404 (Not Found)" in the console if I visit a React Route that contains the calling component (`<FooterPlayer />`)?

I've tried multiple things already, but nothing works or breaks something else.

- `<CollectionTracks />` is a component used in a React Route and `<FooterPlayer />` is not, so I tried adding a route or removing the existing one. The resulting errors didn't make me any wiser.
- using `setupProxy.js` instead of proxy in `package.json`. This fixes the /login and /player, but messes up basically everything else.
- using a catchall `app.get("*")` similar to what I already do for the development environment. This seems to require me to build on every change (I only build when deploying to Heroku).
- trying to implement isomorphism, but this is hugely complicated and I can't find a good reference for implementing it in a existing CRA project. Moreover, the error patterns I see here on SO correspond to what I'm seeing, but the questions all state different problems it seems, so I'm not entirely sure if I should restart my project from an isomorphic base and build the app in there: would it even solve anything?

Comment: Can you check application request URL to `/player` using 'Network' menu in browser's development tools? As well as errors in 'Console' menu.

Comment: Looks like a typo, early closing bracket `)` - `app.get("/player"),` => `app.get("/player", `

Comment: @theusaf *facepalm* thank you so much, can't believe I missed this and almost went full-isomorphic. THANK YOU!